# why docker cp command change /etc/hosts /etc/hostname /etc/resolv.conf owner

Tags: docker

My hosts file owner is admin in docker container, after docker cp command to copy a file into container from physics machine, it's owner has been changed to root.

I want to know why docker do this.

Comment: Please refer to this https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Comment: @GaneshGiri I guess you may misunderstand what I said. For example, I cp file named `test.cfg` from physics machine to docker container. I use command: `sudo docker cp test.cfg <container_id>:/`, before that, I have changed `<container_id>:/etc/hosts` owner to admin, after that, the owner of `<container_id>:/etc/hosts` has been changed to root.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Ganesh,

> files copied to a container are created with UID:GID of the **root** user

Source: [Official docker cp documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

This is because the Docker daemon (actually performing the commands you run) runs as root by default.

If you are simply running commands from your terminal, you can run

```
docker exec [container] chown [user] [file]
```

to change the permissions of the file after you copied it.

If you are copying the file from within a Dockerfile, you can add the --chown option:

```
COPY -chown=admin source-in-host destination-in-container
```